# Why there is such a big jump between require.js and all the other libraries?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, requirejs

i'm trying to implement require.js on my project and i can see that all the libraries are fetched at the same time but the load of require.js not, why is that ?

here is the code i made :

```
require.config({

paths: {

    jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.11.0.min',
    bootstrap:'../bs3/js/bootstrap.min',
    accordion:'accordion-menu/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7',
    scrollTo:'scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min',
    esMainBehavior:'esMainBehavior',
    slimscroll:'../assets/jQuery-slimScroll-1.3.0/jquery.slimscroll',
    nicescroll:'nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll',
    scripts:'scripts',
    mCustomScrollbar: 'jquery.mCustomScrollbar'

},

shim: {

    esMainBehavior:    ["jquery"],
    bootstrap:         ['jquery'],
    accordion:         ["jquery"],
    scrollTo:          ["jquery"],
    slimscroll:        ["jquery"],
    nicescroll:        ["jquery"],
    scripts:           ["jquery"],
    mCustomScrollbar:  ["jquery"]

      }

 })

require([

'esMainBehavior',
'accordion',
'bootstrap',
'scrollTo',
'slimscroll',
'nicescroll',
'scripts',
'mCustomScrollbar'

]);
```

i mean require.js get's fetched at 100ms but all the other libraries are fetched in 400ms

Answer (score 1):

Because `require.js` has to load and execute before it can trigger the loading of the libraries that it is importing.

Comment: It seems kind of weird, I mean...  I thought require.js would load all  the needed libraries a lot more faster than the traditional way but for what I see, it is slower.

Comment: Require will load them on demand and without blocking the rest of the document loading. That may or may not be faster depending on where, exactly, you are looking for performance improvements.